# Kotlin: catch extension

Tags: exception, kotlin

Because Kotlin doesn't support multiple `catch` like java does, I want to create extension to partially solve the problem.

```
fun <T: Throwable>  (() -> Unit).catch(vararg exceptions: KClass<T>, catchBlock: (Throwable) -> Unit) {
    try {
        this()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        if (e::class in exceptions) catchBlock(e) else throw e
    }
}
```

That can be called like this:

```
{
  throw NotImplementedException.exception()
}.catch(NotImplementedException::class) {
   //handle it
}
```

But the problem is that if to pass several arguments with different types it doesn't work (Type inference failed):

```
{
   throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
}.catch(NotImplementedException::class, IndexOutOfBoundsException::class) {

}
```

So how can I change signature of the extension to catch several exceptions of different types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at the types of the two arugments you're trying to pass to your function:

```
val kclass1: KClass<NotImplementedException> = NotImplementedException::class
val kclass2: KClass<IndexOutOfBoundsException> = IndexOutOfBoundsException::class
```

While they are both KClass instances, their type parameters are different - `NotImplementedException` and `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. This means that no generic `T` type parameter can be found for the function that would fit both of these types exactly.

Just for demonstration and explanation purposes, you could help type inference by casting both of your types to `KClass<Throwable>` (or `KClass<Exception>`, or `KClass<RuntimeException`, you get the idea) yourself, that way it could figure out the generic type:

```
{
    throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
}.catch(NotImplementedException::class as KClass<Throwable>, IndexOutOfBoundsException::class as KClass<Throwable>) {
    println("Caught something: $it")
}
```

But the real solution is to use the `out` keyword to specify [use-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) for the type parameter of the `KClass` instances:

```
fun <T : Throwable> (() -> Unit).catch(vararg exceptions: KClass<out T>, catchBlock: (Throwable) -> Unit) {
    try {
        this()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        if (e::class in exceptions) catchBlock(e) else throw e
    }
}
```

This way the compiler will find a type for `T` that's both a subtype of `Throwable` as specified, and is a supertype of all argument's `KClass` type parameters - this will be `RuntimeException` in this case, which you can find out by opening intention actions on the `catch` call (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>⌥↩</kbd> on macOS) and choosing `Add explicit type arguments`. This will produce the following:

```
{
    throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
}.catch<RuntimeException>(NotImplementedException::class, IndexOutOfBoundsException::class) {
    println("Caught something: $it")
}
```

Comment: Minor detail: your version only catches when classes match exactly, but it should cover subclasses as well. The OP has the same problem, of course.